# How to include native debug symbols to Android App Bundle without Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, ndk-build

The documentation for the Android Gradle plugin describes the following way to build your AAB in release mode with native debug symbols included:

```
Android Gradle plugin version 4.1 or later

If your project builds an Android App Bundle, you can automatically include the native debug symbols file in it. To include this file in release builds, add the following to your app's build.gradle file:

android.buildTypes.release.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = { SYMBOL_TABLE | FULL }

Select the debug symbol level from the following:

    Use SYMBOL_TABLE to get function names in the Play Console's symbolicated stack traces. This level supports tombstones.
    Use FULL to get function names, files, and line numbers in the Play Console's symbolicated stack traces.

Note: There is a 300 MB limit for the native debug symbols file. If your debug symbols footprint is too large, use SYMBOL_TABLE instead of FULL to decrease the file size.

If your project builds an APK, use the build.gradle build setting shown earlier to generate the native debug symbols file separately. Manually upload the native debug symbols file to the Google Play Console. As part of the build process, the Android Gradle plugin outputs this file in the following project location:

app/build/outputs/native-debug-symbols/variant-name/native-debug-symbols.zip
```

Since I'm creating an app in V programming language and building an AAB file with `vab` tool (https://github.com/vlang/vab), I don't use Gradle. `vab` handles all needed to build steps and use CLI tools to produce AAB build.

The question is - what modification should I do in `ndk-build` to build a line or AndroidManifest or somewhere else to make the compiler produce debug symbols and pack them into an AAB file?

I tried to search the Web for some kind of command or tutorial, but have found nothing.

I tried to add `-g` and `NDK_DEBUG=1` (found here -> https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-build#dvr) parameters to the `ndk` build CLI command, but I still have a warning in Google Developer Console that my app contains native code and I should include debug symbols.

I also asked ChatGPT about it, but no good answer so far...